# Convert shapefile to tiles for WMS requests

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, wms, tiles, image-pyramids

I have a shapefile (world countries) and this file is fix (I don’t want to edit it). I create a Vector layer with this file in GeoServer and I get this file with WMS layer from GeoServer.

In this pattern, GeoServer create tiles every time I request it the tiles, but I want to create all zoom tiles and save this tiles to disk and then add a pyramid layer to GeoServer.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/tilecache/index.html

Comment: it's good. but I also want to have my wms Server. It means I want to convert fix shp layer to fix tiles and then run my code server to response wms requests(only getMap method).

Comment: Have you tried geoweb cache?

Comment: yes, but I also want to have my wms Server. It means I want to convert fix shp layer to fix tiles and then run my code server to response wms requests(only getMap method).

Comment: that's what GWC does, look at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html